# Object Required or Object variable or With Block errors

Tags: excel, vba, object, variables

I am trying to use VBA to combine data from several different look up ranges for an SQL script writer. At this stage I am trying to identify whether the value I am looking up has an adjacent cell with a specific value. I have tried several iterations. My most recent is the following:

```
   Dim r As String
    With Worksheets(12).Range("q2:R80")
    r = Cells(.Find(u(0, 1).Row, 18)).Value
    End With
```

I have tried with and without the "With" statement as well as with and without "." before the methods and properties and with and with out the ".Value" and no matter what combination I use, I get an object error of some kind or another. I know I am missing something obvious, but Google has been of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses look off:

```
With Worksheets(12).Range("q2:R80")
    r = Cells(.Find(u(0, 1).Row, 18)).Value
End With
```

seems like it should be:

```
With Worksheets(12).Range("q2:R80")
    r = Cells(.Find(u(0, 1)).Row, 18).Value
End With
```

But this is still problematic, becauses it assumes the `Find` succeeded by chaining the `.Row` call.

Better practice is the following:

```
With Worksheets(12).Range("q2:R80")
    Dim foundRng as Range
    Set foundRng = .Find(u(0,1)) '<~ you really should specify the other parameters of Range.Find

    If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then
         r = Cells(foundRng.Row, 18).Value '<~ make sure to qualify the worksheet the Cells are on
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That resolved the error, but now the problem has shifted. The value I'm trying to Find, when compared Cell to Cell on a worksheet matches, but the vba is saying it does not, even though, the value presented in the Watch list is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you specify the other parameters of `Range.Find`? (*LookAt* and *LookIn* especially)

Comment: Never mind. Apparently "Sheet12(Lookups)" in the Objects list does not translate to Worksheets(12). Man I hate the syntax in VBA, though I think it's the error reporting and IDE that get me the most. Appreciate the help @bigben!

Comment: If you want to soup up the IDE a bit, take a look at [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) perhaps.